# How not to allow video upload through html input file upload?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a way to stop users from uploading video to my site. I just want images and GIF.

Is there a javascript method I can apply to prompt users that video format is not allowed?

```
<input type="file">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with,

```
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
```

Comment: A lot of images are now .webp format. How do I handle that?

Comment: with accept add **image/webp**